# ASP.NET MVC 'an error occurred during local report processing at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LcalReport.InternalRender'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting

It's my first time using Reports at ASP.Net, i started with trying to get a simple table as a test but i ended up with an error.
I used the code I found from [here](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2013/09/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4.html)
Of course, i modified it a bit 
Here is the VIEW code :

```
@using System.Data
@model DataTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListQuestionnaire";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layoutadmin.cshtml";
}

<h2 style="margin-top:30px; margin-bottom : 50px;"> Liste Des Questionnaires</h2>
<div class="table-responsive-sm" style="height:300px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
                <tr id="norme">
                    <td style="width:35%;">@row["titre"]</td>
                    <td style="width:35%;">
                        Etat : @row["etat"]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn" id="supp" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Report", "Rapport",new {id= "PDF"})'"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rapport</button>
                        <button class="btn" id="supp" onclick="analyse(@row["id_quest"]);"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Envoyer</button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

and here is the method i got from the code from the link (the only difference is that I'm connecting to the database directly and not using EF ENTITIES) :

```
 public ActionResult Report(string id)
            {
                LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Report.rdlc");
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    lr.ReportPath = path;
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ListQuest");
                }
                SqlConnection con = new 
SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Actions ", con);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                }
                List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", list);
                lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
                string reportType = id;
                string mimeType;
                string encoding;
                string fileNameExtension;



                string deviceInfo =

                "<DeviceInfo>" +
                "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
                "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
                "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
                "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
                "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
                "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
                "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
                "</DeviceInfo>";

                Warning[] warnings;
                string[] streams;
                byte[] renderedBytes;
                try
                {
                    renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                        reportType,
                        deviceInfo,
                        out mimeType,
                        out encoding,
                        out fileNameExtension,
                        out streams,
                        out warnings);

                    return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error rapport : " + ex.Message + ", " + ex.StackTrace);
                    return RedirectToAction("ListQuest");
                }
            }
```

The image [ERROR ENCOUNTRED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAwdU.png) shows what kind of error i get, I tracked it and it stops here :

```
renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                        reportType,
                        deviceInfo,
                        out mimeType,
                        out encoding,
                        out fileNameExtension,
                        out streams,
                        out warnings);

                    return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

I really wish you could help me

Comment: SSRS just doesn’t play nice with mvc mostly and it’s trouble some to implement. If you are just starting out with reports, you can try dotnet Report builder www.dotnetreport.com and see if it works for your requirements. Full disclosure, I’m affiliated with the company.

Comment: Alright, i will try that, thank you